# Android: How to implement WYSIWYG Editor for user content?

Tags: android, wysiwyg

I'm building an Android App where users need to be able to edit their own content, including minimal layout. I just want to store the formatted source in the database and pull it out and display it the way I would with something like TinyMCE in a web app.

Any ideas how users can enter and format their own content in an Android GUI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open source EditText rich text editor called [android-richtexteditor](http://code.google.com/p/android-richtexteditor/) but the code was inexplicably deleted in r5. The [code is still there in r4](http://code.google.com/p/android-richtexteditor/source/browse/?r=4#svn/trunk/src/net/sgoliver) in older revisions; just use svn to check out r4 or earlier to access it.  The code appears to support italics, underline, color picker, text size, and more.

Also answered in these questions:

1. [http://code.google.com/p/android-richtexteditor/](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5632392/403455)
2. [https://stackoverflow.com/q/5632392/403455](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4283755/403455)
3. [https://stackoverflow.com/q/4283755/403455](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3096332/403455)

Answer (score 2):

There is no rich editor widget built into Android. Perhaps you can convince the person who asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096332/style-edittext-content-on-the-fly) an hour or so ago to make his open source.