# Simple rich text editor in Android

Tags: android

How can I implement an editor with font styles, sizes and colors in Android. And how can I save the note and open it after creating the note with all these styles.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283755/android-question-implementing-a-rich-text-editor) will give you some idea

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you store it as HTML? :) Simple as that.

if you want to complicate it a bit, you should store all Spannable data as XML and while parse it and restore the styles when displaying it back.

Comment: Dear Downvoter, please explain why you think my answer is wrong?