# How to create a rich text editor in Android

Tags: android, rich-text-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android question: implementing a rich text editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283755/android-question-implementing-a-rich-text-editor)

How to create Rich Text Editor in Android. It should allow adding text **wherever user clicks** rather than forcing the user to start at left/right by default. Also it should allow adding images and videos. If someone could tell what all I need to know to make an editor with all these requirements it would be of great help.

Comment: First, what you are describing is not a "rich text editor", but some sort of desktop publishing program. Second, "tell what all [you] need to know" to make a desktop publishing program would cost thousands of dollars in consulting fees; expecting StackOverflow (SO) answers on such a broad and advanced topic is unrealistic. SO is more suitable for concrete programming problems than it is for software design and requirements analysis.