# HTML android in android

Tags: android

I want to develop an editor which can make the text bold, italics and underline and create an equivalent HTML for it. I have somethhing like this in my mind:

[image]

When the user clicks on save, I should get HTML data.

For example , if user writes:Hello ***World***

then I should get `<!Doctype HTML><body>Hello <b><i>World</i></b></body></html>`

What are my options here? are there any previous projects like this or do i have to make this from scratch?

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283755/android-question-implementing-a-rich-text-editor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Character Style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html) sub-classes of Android for the styling of your texts. Then use [HTML](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) class to get the HTML equivalent of your text. I'm currently developing one and those are the ones I used. You may also check out https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit for an example on how you could use Character Style for editing. :)