# set fullstop (.) center_vertical with textview android

Tags: android

How to set dot in vertically center of textview example  (. Set .) , I want  both dots in  vertically center of set text. i have been tried with gravity center but didnt get any success, You can refer attached image where  dot show after just now with very light color, i want same , so please suggest how to achieve this

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a bullet character, `\u00b7`

Answer (score 3):

There is no way you can do this in the way you are trying to do it.

Remember, fullstop may look as just a dot, but in reality, there is empty space above the dot. From bitmap perspective, it is as tall as any other character.

You may, however, try below 2 approaches:

1. Use different character instead of fullstop. e.g. "\u00B7". It looks like `·set·`
2. Change the font size of just `.` (not possible in simple textview, AFAIK. Possible in [rich text edit boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283755/android-question-implementing-a-rich-text-editor).)

Answer (score 1):

Set margin from top in negative(like -10dp).

Comment: don't know if its the right fix, but it does work.