# wants to make toggle Bold Button which makes next coming text BOLD ANDROID

Tags: android, android-edittext, rich-text-editor

I am making Rich Text Editor for android.like basic Rich text Editor.I want to perform basic
function on toggle like BOLD the Text.I am successful with making selected text bold.but i want basic bold function like want bold button is ON next text should be in bold and when BOLD is OFF the next text should be in normal and same button can also make the selected text BOLD

Hera is my Code please Check it Currently i am doing it with basic button

```
message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note);
    final Button bold = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bold); 
    bold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    //  message.setTypeface(message.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);

            int startSelection = message.getSelectionStart();
            int endSelection = message.getSelectionEnd();
            Spannable s = message.getText();
            s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), startSelection, endSelection, 0);

}
    });
```

I want basic functionality which use Ms Word for BOLD then i will implement it to italic , Normal ,Underline , Color change , etc

Comment: Have you tried this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096332/style-edittext-content-on-the-fly ? It works almost fine.